# Is it called "the filter/strainer/cover/seive of my bathroom drain"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

This is the drain in my bathroom

**What is the piece of metal with many holes called?**

Is it called "**the filter/strainer/cover/sieve of my bathroom drain**" in casual everyday English?

Comment: In the UK, we call often that a **grate**, or more specifically, a **drain grate**.

Comment: I might call it a **grill** - [*a framework of metal bars used as a partition or a grate.*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/grill)

Comment: [Grate cover](https://www.amazon.co.uk/grate-covers-drains/s?k=grate+covers+for+drains) or "Drain guard"

Comment: In American English you'll also sometimes hear "**drain catcher**" or "**drain catch**" as well as "**drain screen**".

Answer (score 0):

The piece of metal with many holes that are used to prevent debris from going down the drain in your bathroom is commonly referred to as the "drain cover" or "drain strainer." These terms are often used interchangeably to describe the same object. Some people may also refer to it as a "drain filter" or "drain sieve." The specific terminology used may vary depending on regional or individual preferences, but any of these terms should generally be understood to refer to the same item.

Comment: To me (a Brit), a "drain cover" is a *cowling* (usually, moulded plastic) that fits over an ***outside*** "grated drainhole" - whose primary purpose is to prevent autumn leaves from building up and blocking the grating underneath.

Comment: It's fascinating to see regional variations in terminologies and solutions for common problems.

Comment: I also wouldn't call this a "drain cover" - to me (mid-Atlantic American), "drain cover" means a "drain stop" - a flexible rubber circle that is used to actually prevent water from leaving the basin.  Likely any of these would be OK and the meaning would be clear from context, however.

Comment: Google suggests "drain strainer" usually refers to a detachable device placed over the drain, rather than the fixed grille. I'd prefer grille, grill, grating, or cover. "Sieve" sounds even wronger - that almost always refers to a separate object, usually with a handle or handles, mostly in a kitchen although also for soil.